# Find average and then use that value to calculate other values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query with a few columns. I need to find the avg of a particular column and then use the average value to calculate other values.

I am finding avg with `select avg(col1) as mean from tablea`.
Now I want to use the mean value to calculate other values.
I tried:

```
select avg(col1) as mean, col2 - 2(avg(col1)
from table a
group by col2.
```

The problem is query should return only one row, but it is returning many rows based on `col2`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your complete SQL. A DBFiddle is a good way to do this.

Comment: `col2 - 2(avg(col1)` doesn't look valid?

Comment: If your question is how to reuse `avg(col1)` then you need to either calculate it everywhere you need it, or use a sub-query or some sort.

Comment: You obviously cannot use any column that is out of context: either aggregate the column or use it as a group column. In your case `col2` is not aggregated, so the result will have as many rows as there are distinct values of this column

Comment: 'query should return only one row,', how so? you want to use col2 in the results, wouldn't col2 have different values in different rows? which single value of col2 would you want used in the result?

Comment: It would look something like select col2, min(col2 - 2*(select avg(col1) from table))
from table a
group by col2

Comment: Seems odd to group by the same field that is used in a calculation. As already advised, sample data and desired output would be helpful. You want a record for each unique value in col2? Or do you want to sum col2?

Comment: Sounds like you should remove `GROUP BY col2` but hard to say without sample data

Comment: Possibly: `avg(count(*) * avg(col1)) over ()`

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I was not aware of DBFIDDLE. I was able to achieve what i was looking for by using CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Nest query.

```
SELECT col2, col2 - 2*(SELECT Avg(col1) AS mean FROM tablea) AS Calc 
FROM tablea
GROUP BY col2
```